# Pop-up box in the middle of C# / ASP.NET code

Tags: c#, asp.net, messagebox

Here's what I want to do: the user selects data from a table. Sometimes it's a lot of data. Like, more than they really want, and it takes forever to get into the gridview.

So, what I'd like to do is run part of the code, count the number of records in the data, and *then* prompt the user with the number of records and confirm they actually want to sit and wait for it all.  How would I do this?

My C# code is below:

```
protected void btnAARDetails_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ARDays = txtARDays.Text;
    string dAARState = ddlAARState.SelectedValue;
    string dAARSystem = ddlAARSystem.SelectedValue;

    OracleConnection conn = GetConnection();
    try
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SP_LPI_MAINT_AA_ARCHIVE_DETAIL", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("vDays", OracleType.Number).Value = ARDays;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("vState", OracleType.VarChar).Value = dAARState;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("vSystem", OracleType.VarChar).Value = dAARSystem;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("vResult", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                conn.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                GridView_Reports.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
                var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "MyTableName");

                int RCNT = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO USE 'RCNT' IN A Yes/No MESSAGEBOX

                GridView_Reports.Visible = true;
                GridView_Reports.DataSource = ds;
                GridView_Reports.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Button), "Report Menu", "alert('Error: " + ex + "')", true);
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return;
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a web app, no easy message boxes. What you can do is send first request to the server asking for number of records only, present some kind of message on your webpage, and after confirmation send second request for all the data. Alternatively, have you considered pagination?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegisterStartupScript` like

```
private void Prompt(string val)
{
  string script = string.Format("alert(\"{0}\");", val);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), 
                      "ServerControlScript", script, true);
}
```

In your button click handler call it

```
           int RCNT = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
           Prompt(RCNT.ToString());
```

Also check this CodeProject article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7525/Simple-MessageBox-functionality-in-ASP-NET

Comment: I knew about RegisterStartupScript, and this doesn't give me a Yes/No option.  Most messageboxes I've seen only happen "on click", I need this to happen mid-script.